# lightning button menu alignment

Tags: lightning-aura-components, slds, lightning-buttonmenu

I have implemented lightning:buttonMenu but when it opens its alignment is towards right. Can we make it to left side?

```
                    <div class="slds-shrink-none"> 
                        <lightning:buttonMenu
                          iconSize="small"
                          variant="border-filled"
                          alternativeText="Menu"
                          onselect="{! c.handleMenuSelect }">
   <lightning:menuItem label="Edit Contact" value="{!pcr.ConId}" />                          
   <lightning:menuItem label="Delete Team" value="{!pcr.Id}" />
   <lightning:menuItem label="Edit Role" value="{!pcr.Id +'Role'}" />                         
  
</lightning:buttonMenu>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In button menu use menuAligment

<lightning:buttonMenu menuAlignment="right" iconSize="small" variant="border-filled" alternativeText="Menu" onselect="{! c.handleMenuSelect }">

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:buttonMenu/specification

Comment: How is this different from what the markup in the question already contains?

Comment: Oh, sorry I forgot input the menuAlignment rs Now is correct => <lightning:buttonMenu menuAlignment="right" iconSize="small" variant="border-filled" alternativeText="Menu" onselect="{! c.handleMenuSelect }">